# Inconsistent math font size in table cell with dcolumn

Tags: fontsize, dcolumn

Some cells in my table contain numbers that have to be aligned around the decimal separator. So, I use `dcolumn` to produce the desired alignment. Some of the cells, however, have to be written out with a **smaller font size** while keeping the same alignment around the decimal separator.
Unfortunately, these latter cells display an **inconsistent behavior** in their font size: the font size remains smaller up to the decimal separator, while returning to the normal font size in the subsequent digits. I produce hereby a MWE using the `standalone` class for mere purposes of representation.

I have already attempted some alternatives, for instance using the package `relsize` and its related command `\mathsmaller`. None of my numerous attempts took me anywhere. Moreover, I could not find this type of issue being documented anywhere else.

Can anybody help solve this inconsistency in the font size?

```
% Minimal Working Example
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{2.3}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c.}
    Header A    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Header B} \\
    Item 1  & -0.522 \\
    \scriptsize(Item 2)  & \scriptstyle 0.001
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Visual output of MWE]

Comment: the `D` column type splits the contents on the decimal and then typesets things in a special way. So if you have `\foo L.R` you end up with `SOMETHING{\too L}.{SOMETHING{R}` and this `\foo` never reaches the `R` part in the typesetting. As an alternative to `dcolumn` have a look at `siunitx`, besides typesetting units it also typesets table data, and its font handling is a lot better, though you'd use `\scriptsize` not `\scriptstyle`.

Answer (score 5):

Adding additional `\scriptstyle` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{2.3}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c.}
    Header A    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Header B} \\
    Item 1  & -0.522 \\
    \scriptsize(Item 2)  & \scriptstyle 0.\scriptstyle001
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, but how can that be automatized into a new column type via `dcolumn`? For instance, one may first define a colum type `T` which aligns numbers around the separator and then define a further colum type `t` that simply smallens the font size of `T`. By means of an example, one could add the column types `\newcolumntype{T}{D{.}{.}{2.3}}` and `\newcolumntype{t}{{\scriptstyle}>T} `. Except that the inconsistency highlighted in the question prevents this type of automation.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not tied to `dcolumn`, you could try with `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c S[table-format=-1.3]}
    Header A    & {Header B} \\
    Item 1  & -0.522 \\
    \scriptsize(Item 2)  & \scriptsize 0.001
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]